# How to use Rxjs 5.5 `first` operator which has mismatch type in arguments?

Tags: rxjs

I'm using an  [*external package*](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/blob/cfa1440568da5f794beca5028aad1c8b8189c3a9/lib/src/translate.service.ts#L392) which emits an Observable :

```
getValue(key: string | Array<string>, interpolateParams?: Object): Observable<string | any> {
    return null;
  }
```

I also  use the `first` lettable operator  :

```
import { first } from "rxjs/operators/first";
this.getValue('f').let(first);
```

But I'm getting an error  :

> Type 'Observable' provides no match for the signature '(value:
>   any, index: number, source: Observable): value is any'.

I can see where the problem comes from.
The `first` operator is :

> export function first(predicate?: (value: T, index: number, source:
>   Observable) => boolean): MonoTypeOperatorFunction;

And my Observable is type `<any>`

**Question:**

How can I fix my `lettable` operator to work with the Observable ^ ?

[**Online-demo which shows the problem**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ttxtuw?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call first in the `let`. It will return a function which will be applied by the stream. Also use `pipe` instead if `let`

```
this.getValue('f').pipe(first())
```

Comment: The thing which confused me is that  , if it were `map` then `map(a=>..)` must be supplied , and it's an invocation `()` . But with first , I forgot to invoke it also :). It happens. Thanks

Comment: @RoyiNamir pipe is new

Comment: I mean this : https://i.imgur.com/OMrDw42.jpg   - I'm using 5.5.2 (pipe does work  , but not `let`)